# go build error "db.GetUsers undefined (type *gorm.DB has no field or method GetUsers)"

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am new to golang and trying to make API server using gin + gorm.
I tried to build the code below but I am getting `type *gorm.DB has no field or method GetUsers` error.
This is a very simple API server and only I want to do is get all users from `users` table.

```
package models

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost dbname=test user=postgres password=test sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}

type User struct {
   ID           int    `json:"id"`
   Username     string `json:"name"`
}

func NewUser(id int, name string) User {
    return User{
      ID:           id,
      Username:     name,
    }
}

// UserRepository
type UserRepository struct {
}

func NewUserRepository() UserRepository {
    return UserRepository{}
}

func (m UserRepository) GetUsers() []*User {
    var users []*User
    has, _ := db.GetUsers(&users)
    if has {
         return users
    }
    return nil
}
```

I implemented `GetUsers()` in `controllers/user.go`and I also created `users` table.
I have no idea why it says `no field or method GetUsers`.Someone give me an advice to solve this.

```
package controllers

import (
     "api-server/models"
)

type User struct {
}

func NewUser() User {
     return User{}
}

func (c User) GetUsers() interface{} {
     repo := models.NewUserRepository()
     user := repo.GetUsers()
     return user
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to comment back to your question under Sergey's answer above, but I don't have the privilege since I'm new here.

As Sergey said, I cannot see GetUsers function in `gorm.DB` struct. If you do `db.Raw("select * from users").Scan(&users)`, you cannot (don't need to either) assign two variables to the statement. Instead, just:

```
db.Raw("select * from users").Scan(&users)
```

This is because DB.Scan() returns only one result variable in your DB implementation:

```
// Scan scan value to a struct
func (s *DB) Scan(dest interface{}) *DB {
    return s.clone().NewScope(s.Value).Set("gorm:query_destination",dest).callCallbacks(s.parent.callbacks.queries).db
}
```

### Updated answer after more context was added to the question:

That is because you didn't actually implement `GetUsers` for `gorm.DB`. What you did was - define a struct in `controllers` package named `User`, and attach a `GetUsers` method to that struct. Inside `controllers/User.GetUsers` you called `repo.GetUsers` which internally tries to call `db.GetUsers`. `db` is of type `*gorm.DB` which does not have `GetUsers` method defined.

One way to fix is as Sergey suggested, just do `db.Raw(...).Scan(...)`.

If you really want to encapsulate gorm.DB and makes `GetUsers` look more native from the db connection, one thing you can try is:

```
type MyDB struct {
    gorm.DB
}
func (m *MyDB) GetUsers() []*Users {
    // do things like m.Raw(...).Scan(...)
}
```

And in your models, you declare `db` as type `*MyDB` instead of `*gorm.DB`.

For more official docs about this embedding technique, checkout https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Comment: Thank you for the comment Jingchao.Sorry for the lack of explanation.I have `GetUsers` function in `controllers/user.go`.I imported `models` package in controller.

Comment: Ok, that's because you implemented `GetUsers` for the struct `User` in package `controller`, but in your code you are doing `db.GetUsers(&users)`, where `db` is of type `*gorm.DB`. `*DB` in `github.com/jinzhu/gorm` itself does not implement function `GetUsers`.

Answer (score 1):

If I see in your code I don't see GetUsers function
db this *gorm.DB and not have GetUsers
You need like this

 `db..Raw("select * from users").Scan(&users)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I changed the code but
`has, _ := db.Raw("select * from users").Scan(&users)` 
returns `assignment count mismatch: 2 = 1` error.